# Identification of an aromatic compound for a quiz

Tags: organic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, molecules, identification

I need help identifying this structure for a puzzle. Original text was blurry, so a white overlay was added for readability, though some fragments might be different. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

[image: an image of an unknown molecule structure with added white text]
[image: an image of an unknown molecule structure]

Comment: I suppose the SO3 groups make it water-soluble. Does not really look like a dye (yet could be), I would rather bet on pharmaceutical.

Answer (score 4):

I would expect neither Ne (Na only), nor 8 (3 only) for the marked fragments on the given structure. Both groups are most likely just sodium sulfonate $\ce{-SO3^-Na+}$ fragments. The name generated by [MarvinSketch](https://www.chemaxon.com/products/marvin/marvinsketch/) for the given structure is *disodium 4‐(3‐carbamoyl‐5‐acetamidobenzamido)benzene‐1,3‐disulfonate*:

[image]

Comment: using this in a substructure search in chemspider gives this neat looking thing : http://www.chemspider.com/Chemical-Structure.9564201.html I guess this image could be part of that.

Comment: @gilleain Good find, I guess your comment might as well be an answer:)